# Explain how multiple variable assignment in single line works? (Example: a, b = b, a+b)

Tags: python

Say I have this Python code

```
def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

For `n=1000` this prints:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
```

But I don't understand why it's `1 1 2 3`.

The issue is with this line:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

What is the order of execution? 
The two options I see are:

**1**:

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

**2**:

```
b = a+b
a = b
```

But neither gives me the correct result when I try it manually.
What am I missing?

Comment: "But I don't understand why it's `1 1 2 3`" - ummm, that's the Fibonacci sequence, what's the problem?

Comment: I know it's Fibonacci. I know this is the answer. I don't understand how the code does it due to the assignment line I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the two options you shared actually describe the working of:

```
a, b = b, a+b
```

Above code assigns `a` with the value of `b`. And `b` with the older value of `a+b` (i.e. in `a+b` the older value of `a`). You may consider it as an equivalent of:

```
>>> temp_a, temp_b = a, b
>>> a = temp_b
>>> b = temp_a + temp_b
```

**Example:** Dual variable assignment in one line:

```
>>> a, b = 3, 5
>>> a, b = b, a+b
>>> a
5
>>> b
8
```

Equivalent Explicit Logic:

```
>>> a, b = 3, 5
>>> temp_a, temp_b = a, b
>>> a = temp_b
>>> b = temp_a + temp_b
>>> a
5
>>> b
8
```

Comment: Thanks. Where does the tutorial of Python explain this? This is not trivial

Answer (score 2):

The order of operations in `a, b = b, a+b` is that the tuple `(b, a+b)` is constructed, and then that tuple is assigned to the variables `(a, b)`.  In other words, the right side of the assignment is entirely evaluated before the left side.

(Actually, starting with Python 2.6, no tuple is actually constructed in cases like this with up to 3 variables - a more efficient series of bytecode operations gets substituted.  But this is, by design, not a change that has any observable differences.)

Answer (score 0):

It's python standard way to swap two variables, Here is a working example to clear your doubt,

> > Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while
> >     evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the
> >     left-hand side.
>
> http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i,j in enumerate(a):
    if i==1:
        a[i-1],a[i]=a[i],a[i-1]

print(a)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For more info , [read this tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/swap-variables)